# How to Reshape Floating Action Button And Add BottomNavBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-bottomnavigation, bottom-navigation-bar

[image]

Hello Everyone! I am new In Flutter Framework i need a help from you guys. Actually I just want to design the bottom navbar with page shifting like. When use clicks on The Following tabs than the screen will change but bottom nav bar has to be fixed on the bottom. and I need same design of floating action button which is shown in This Image.

```
floatingActionButtonLocation : FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: Container(
          height: 64,
          width: 62,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){},
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          //foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          elevation: 8.0,
          shape: const const CircleBorder(),,
          child: const ImageIcon(AssetImage('Assets/Images/Rupeyo-logo-icon.png'), color: Color(0XFFDF2C25), size: 39,),
          
          ),
        ), 
        bottomNavigationBar:  BottomAppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Container(
          height: 30,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0.0),
                  child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                  Icon(Icons.border_all_outlined,
                  color:Colors.grey),
                  Text('Category', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10),)
                  
                ],
              ),
              ),
                 Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 45.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                  color:Colors.grey  ),
                  Text('WishList', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10),)
                  
                ],
              ),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 35.0),
                  child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                  Icon(Icons.local_mall_outlined,
                  color:Colors.grey),
                  Text('Order', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10),),
                ],
              ),
              ),
                 Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                  color:Colors.grey),
                  Text('Cart', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 10),)
                ],
               ),
              ), 
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: you can add the `BottomNavigationBar` widget will your items as stated in one answer, and use `FloatingActionButton` for the icon that shows above the item in navbar in design. Wrap it with `Align` and center it.

Comment: Thanks For your Response Clevino But I already implented this in my code my question was different i want to remove bottom border of floating action button and only want to display top border. like this https://www2.online-converting.com/upload/api_712b20dc29/result.jpg

Comment: can you try this answer? Add top margin to the floating action button container and copy the boxShadow with black color...https://stackoverflow.com/a/68836578/18645340

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple BottomNavBar which sticks on the bottom even shifting page for your reference.

Here HomePage(),AddActivity(),Notificationss(),ProfilePage() are the pages that slides according to navbar clicked.Be sure to design your bottomnavbar as you wish

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void onTapImplemented(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    const HomePage(),
    const AddActivity(),
    const Notificationss(),
    const ProfilePage(),
  ];
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Social Event App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
              seedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
              primary: Colors.black,
              secondary: Colors.white),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add_outlined),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                label: '',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                label: '',
              ),
            ],
            selectedItemColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
            unselectedItemColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 146, 138, 138),
            selectedFontSize: 0,
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            onTap: onTapImplemented,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Also take references from [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

Comment: Thanku For Your Response Suman But I Am Stuked at this  part "body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex)," how i can implement this in my code. please see this image https://www2.online-converting.com/upload/api_d3a0207b7a/result.jpg and help to implement it.

Comment: Your code is not so readable but what I can see is you haven't used onTap property of BottomNavigationBar.And I also think currentindex property is mandatory .Please research for further

Comment: Actually I have just Created Bottom Navigation Bar In Other page and Give The Current Index name is home and it's Worked For Me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to circular shape Floating Action button you can try this code. I hope this will help you.

```
floatingActionButton: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF2945ED),
      child: const Icon(
        Icons.shopping_cart,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 30,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: But I want to remove Bottom Border and Only Display Top Border Of The circle of Floating Action Button Like This. https://www2.online-converting.com/upload/api_712b20dc29/result.jpg

Comment: Your question did not seem like that is what you wanted, please update your question with a specific reason.